# How can I host a TF model and train it with different data sets via an API so I can latter access the different trained models via an API?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, server, backend

I have an untrained Keras model. I want to somehow host this untrained model and then be able to train it with different data sets and save the differet trained models via an API. Then I would like to make predictions with the different trained models via an API.

This is the first time I try to develop a backend service that involves machine learning (not only prediction but also training). Normally I work with express but I'm wondering if the best way is to create a Django API that receives the data to train, loads the model from AWS S3 and the somehow runs a routine that trains the model with the data and sabes the result in S3.Finally when I want to make a prediction I can load the model and make a prediction in the Django app when I receive an API call.

Im not sure how would the whole pipeline work. I appreciate any comments.

In reality the idea is to have multiple models but I would like to know how it would work with 1 before thinking about multiple.

Comment: Is your plan to host the Django server on a personal machine? Or inside AWS?

Comment: @20r25g22e I want to host everything on AWS. the thing is, I know how to deploy a basic web app in express or Django. The thing im not so sure about is how what is the best approach to store and train ML models. Should I store models in s3 and then spin up an EC2 instance to train a model and then store it? Any comments will be very helpful since I haven't been able to find resources that touch on this topic.